# Does the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means hold in the limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The inequality of arithmetic and geometric means suggests for $t$ nonnegative real numbers $x_1,\dots,x_t$ that
$$\frac{\sum_{s=1}^t x_s}{t}\geq\left(\prod_{s=1}^t x_s\right)^\frac{1}{t}.$$
Does it imply for the sequence of nonnegative real number, $\{x_s\}_{s=1}^\infty$, that
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{s=1}^t x_s}{t}\geq\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\left(\prod_{s=1}^t x_s\right)^\frac{1}{t}?$$
What condition(s) I need?

Comment: Think about them as sequences. If you have two convergent sequences such that $a_n \geq b_n$, do we have $ a \geq b$?  On a separate note, the limit might not exist, esp if $x_i$ is unbounded.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose $x_i$ is bounded. What are the other conditions for the existence of the limit?

Comment: Why, many. Imagine a sequence $1,2,2,1,1,1,1,\underbrace{2\,\dots\,2}_{8\;
 times}\dots$